# Importing submodule with python for QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

So I am probably missing something really obvious here, but for some reason, I can't import submodules in my python plugin.

This is the general structure of my plugin:

```
├── __init__.py
├── metadata.txt
├── pluginMain.py
├── plugin_ui.py
├── plugin_ui.ui
├── resources.qrc
├── resources_rc.py
├── sub
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── qcf.py
├── ui.py
```

I'm trying to import the qcf file from the sub module, but for some reason, this simple snippet fails to execute when QGIS calls it:

```
import sub.qcf
print sub.qcf
```

This is (part of) the stacktrace I receive:

```
File "/Users/.../.qgis2/python/plugins/.../ui.py", line 26, in 
    print sub.qcf
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'qcf'
```

As you can see, importing works fine, but actually using the submodule does not work.

When I try to run the same code from within the python shell (in the top level directory), everything works as it should:

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec  7 2015, 12:36:04)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sub.qcf
>>> print sub.qcf
<module 'sub.qcf' from 'sub/qcf.pyc'>
```

So, why does this simple import not work from within QGIS and is there any way to solve this?

Comment: As a temporary solution, importing qcf in the __init__ file of the sub packages fixes the issue.